# Consensys would like to run a answer campaign, any ideas of things to take into account?

Tags: discussion, moderation, events

[Consensys](https://consensys.net/), the company I work for, is currently leading a community effort to resolve as many unanswered question on the Ethereum Stack Exchange as possible.

We planed this campaign to post on Ethereum SE **from May 30th to June 12th**.

Most posters will be Consensys employees but also general community devs.
Some will be first time posters (so some answers will go directly to moderation first post queue), others have experience and rep on this site already and will try to make sure that everything goes smoothly (like me posting this message here).
For transparency, we are requesting that Consensys employees note it in their profile. We hope that some of them will continue contributing to SE after this campaign of course.

Do you have any suggestions to make this initiative most effective or concerns about it in any way ?

Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, thanks for helping out!

1. Vote. Find good questions and answers that haven't seen a lot of activity, and just give them an upvote.
2. Ask questions. Answers are great, but keep in mind that we also encourage self-answering questions. While cleaning up unanswered questions is great, keep in mind that without interesting questions we cannot have interesting answers. Think of things you were stuck on for a while, and ask a question about it.
3. Community Wikis. Answers asking for e.g. a list of tools may be best answered as a [community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts).
4. Avoid unnecessary self-promotion. It's fine if a ConsenSys product or tool would be a constructive answer to a question, but please disclose your affiliation in the answer.
5. Follow the rules. If you're unsure of whether something is OK, check the [help center](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help) or the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites). If it's still unclear, ask a meta question!

One of the best things companies can do for us is just encourage their developers to actively participate on the SE. Even if you could figure out an issue on your own, asking a question here builds the community knowledge and saves future developers from having to redo the work to solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will make sure our team understands that.